# Is it possible for a java process in one jvm to kill/stop another java process in another jvm?

Tags: java, process, jvm, ipc

If so, how can I find out which process is it(out of all the others on the system) and how do I kill it such that its shutdownhook gets executed?

Reason I want to do this is because I want to implement something like apache start, apache stop whereby after invoking apache start or apache stop, a server process starts or stops in the background and I get the command or bash prompt back; this is suppose to work on both linux and windows.

Answer (score 4):

It's possible, but it will be operating system specific. There's nothing in the JVM that automatically gives you access to kill other VMs.

You'll either need to call your operating system's `kill` command (or equivalent) or write some native code.

It can be done, and if you're only going to run on unix-like systems, then your best option would be to write a shell script that does what you want, and then execute it with `ProcessBuilder` and friends.

Answer (score 2):

U can think about opening a service on servant side ,which is for close itself, to be handled by the master application.

On the other hand, if u do not want to do it, u need to find a way to get the processes of a jvm instance. If u just want to kill jvm, it would be easy but for a specific process. U need some help I think, like this:

[link](http://www.irixtech.com/java/hacks/kill-specific-java-process-windows-xp)

Hope it works for u

Comment: I've thought about the socket thing but decided against that as it would be rather risky for a server to expose another socket to the world where anyone can send a fake message to it(even with SSL enabled) unless of course that socket listens only to connections from the localhost and not over the network, is that possible?

Comment: Of course it is possible. U can define permissions for your master app to your firewall and prevent your system from attacks.  And also, the idea of giving the responsibility to close the application to the application itself, is a good thing I think.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use JMX.

You can start  a JMX server in your java process, and open some API like start and stop.

With JMX, you don't need to implement anything about socket and permission. You just need to provide a function called by remote with JMX. You can also set a user and password for access.